# openssl and OCSP

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to check the revocation of certificates in a script but I'm getting the following error:

```
unable to load certificate
140735258465104:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

Here are the steps (using www.google.com as an example).

1. fetch the certificate

   ```
   $ echo 'Q' | openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 > google.crt
   ```
2. extract the URI of the issuer

   ```
   $ openssl x509 -in google.crt -text -noout | grep 'CA Issuers' | \
       sed -e "s/^.*CA Issuers - URI://
   ```

   this gives `http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crt`
3. fetch the issuer certificate

   ```
   $ curl --silent http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crt > issuer.crt
   ```
4. extract the OCSP URI

   ```
   $ openssl x509 -in google.crt -ocsp_uri -noout
   ```

   this gives `http://clients1.google.com/ocsp`

And now the final step:

```
$ openssl ocsp -no_nonce -issuer issuer.crt -cert google.crt \
      -url http://clients1.google.com/ocsp
unable to load certificate
140735258465104:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I just saw that `http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crt` is in DER format. Converting it to PEM with

```
$ openssl x509 -inform DER -outform PEM -in issuer.der -out issuer.pem
```

brings me one step further, but

```
$ openssl ocsp -no_nonce -issuer issuer.pem -cert google.crt \
      -url http://clients1.google.com/ocsp
Error querying OCSP responder
140735258465104:error:27076072:OCSP routines:PARSE_HTTP_LINE1:server response error:ocsp_ht.c:255:Code=404,Reason=Not Found
```

The error kind of makes sense since http://clients1.google.com/ocsp delivers a 404 but the URL is the one stored in the original certificate ...

The next question will also be how to automatically detect the format of the issuer certificate but I could use `file` and see if the file is binary or ASCII.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set a `Host` header. There's an undocumented command-line flag for this. Try:

```
openssl ocsp -no_nonce -issuer issuer.pem -cert google.crt \
    -url http://clients1.google.com/ocsp \
    -header Host clients1.google.com
```

Comment: Great tip. Do you know a reason, why this is neccesary?

Comment: Since OCSP communicates over HTTP, a web-server is contacted and the appropriate web-application (virtual host) may only get triggered by the web-server when the Host header is passed.  It might be possible that some sites dedicate IPs for OCSP so that no Host header is required.

Comment: Should it be  -header Host clients.1.google.com, or -header Hosts=clients.1.google.com? I got error message when use first from: Missing = in header key=value
ocsp: Use -help for summary.